# React / Redux passing props to main component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am still quite confused about data flow in React / Redux build. I am fairly comfortable when working "in" my app but I can't figure out how to pass data to my app from server?

I have react-app.php file with `article#main-content` element which is base element for my app. I want to pass the element information about some product.

How do I do that?

I wanted to give `article#main-content` prop productName but I don't know how to access it from react.

My guess is from reducer ... but how? Maybe I should not relly on `article#main-content` and pass variables to react in `$_GET` parameters?

react-app.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lines-configurator/build/style.css" media="screen"/>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="/lines-configurator/build/bundle.js"></script>

<article id="main-content" productName="My Product">
</article>
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reducer from './reducers/index';

import BoardConfig from './containers/BoardConfigContainer';
import BoardProduct from './containers/BoardProductContainer';

const store = createStore(reducer, window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension());

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
            <BoardConfig />
            <BoardProduct />
        </div>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('main-content')
);
```

BoardProductContainer.js

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import BoardProduct from '../components/BoardProductComponent';

export default connect(
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {

        };
    },
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {};
    }
)(BoardProduct);
```

BoardProductComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function () {
    return ();
}
```

BoardProductReducer.js

```
import * as types from '../constants/constants';
import Immutable from 'immutable';

const initialState = Immutable.Map({});

export default function boardReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get url parameters from

```
this.props.location.query
```

Ex:

```
// http://localhost:3000/?test=1

console.log(this.props.location.query);
/*
{
  test: "1"
}
*/
```

---

### Passing server vars other than $_GET

Normally you would call and action that makes an ajax request and return in the reducer.

But since you already have a value since the beginning what you can do is wrap the code of your App.js in a `start` function

```
export default function start(serverVar) {
    // use serverVar here:
    const store = createStore(reducer, window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension());

    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div>
                <BoardConfig />
                <BoardProduct />
            </div>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('main-content')
    );
}
```

Change your webpack's output to include:

```
library: 'Foo'
```

On your html file add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Foo.start('<?php echo $serverVar; ?>');
</script>
```

#### Or simply

Ignore all the setup above and just do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.someValue = '<?php echo $serverVar; ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: I feel so bad for not using ajax request but I will go with global window value. :D Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally create an action, with the following flow:

- Dispatch event { type: GETTING_DATA, status: IN_PROGRESS }. Now based on this, the reducer could modify the state such that you can display a spinner or whatever element you prefer, to let the user know data is loading.
- Perform AJAX request to the server and get the data.
- a) Dispatch event { type: GETTING_DATA, status: SUCCESS } if the data was retrieved successfully. The reducer can now update the state and your component will re-render.
- b) Dispatch event { type: GETTING_DATA, status: FAILED } if there was a problem while retrieving data. The reducer can now modify the state in such a way that the user knows some error occurred.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why ajax request? I have the data in variable in react-app.php. I just want to pass them to my react components. But I guess I could always fetch the data because I know uri so ... that might be cleaner than passing them with php.

Comment: If you want to access the data you have in the file from React, you can follow a similar pattern. Create an action that gets the data. Get the data using jQuery for example (`$('#main-content).attr("productName")`). Trigger an event that says it's all done and put it in the state. The aforementioned action can be triggered in the componentWillMount function so that the data will be available by the time the component mounted.

Answer (score 1):

I do this differently. I define global javaScript variables in the html head when I am rendering my page in php - I am using a blade template, so mine looks like this:

```
var orgUnitIdGlobal = {!! json_encode($orgUnitId, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) !!};
```

Then in my app.js I can call on that variable:

```js
var elementId = 'appRoot';
if (document.getElementById(elementId)) {
 let store = createStore(reducer,{
  orgUnitId : orgUnitIdGlobal
 });
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
   <MyComponent />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById(elementId)
 )
}
```

the 'orgUnitId' is then passed through to my reducer:

```
import orgUnitId from './orgUnitId.js'
...other reducers for other parts of the state...
export default combineReducers({
    orgUnitId,
...other reducers....
})
```

and as i pass {orgUnitId: orgUnitIdGlobal} as the second parameter to my createStore, it is passed through as the state in the call to the orgUnitId(state,action) when the component is being initialised.

I can then refer to that value (I think) from other reducers, and make what ever API calls I need - like api.com/getname?orgUnitId=7 in the getName reducer.....

Comment: Looking back at this question I believe everything is fine as long as there is at least a little bit of dependency injection. (one place where php -> javascript values are passed) I ended up doing the same thing as you but I had to get the global window variables inside my nested stores.